# HtmlUnit: WebClient enabled JavaScript, but still got JavaScript load error

Tags: htmlunit

Tried to create a test using HTMLUnit for Confluence and had to login. But getting error that 'Javascript load error'. I am quite new to HTMLUnit and have only basic knowledge.

Tried for Chrome, Firefox.

Code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://<domain>.atlassian.net");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Part of the HTML page parsed:

```
    <div id="root">
      <noscript>
        &lt;div class="scriptLoadError"&gt;&lt;div class="container"&gt;&lt;h1 class="logo"&gt;Atlassian&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;div class="heading"&gt;JavaScript is disabled&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="content"&gt;&lt;p&gt;You should enable JavaScript to work with this page.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
      </noscript>
      <div id="javaScriptLoadError" style="display: block;">
        <div class="scriptLoadError">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="logo">
              Atlassian
            </h1>
            <div class="heading">
              JavaScript load error
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <p>
                We tried to load scripts but something went wrong.
              </p>
              <p>
                Please make sure that your network settings allow you to download scripts from the following domain:
              </p>
              <p>
                <b>
                  https://aid-frontend.prod.atl-paas.net/atlassian-id/front-end/5.0.392
                </b>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script nonce="OtVvyH6YLHv/RlgULCwPrLjIMu8=">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){document.getElementById("javaScriptLoadError")&&(document.getElementById("javaScriptLoadError").style.display="block")}
//]]>
```

When I tried using Selenium, it worked fine from the same system.
It would be of great help if someone could help me.

Comment: Where is this HTML coming from? (and the `<noscript>` content should not be HTML-encoded).

Comment: Hello! Tested the Atlassian login and reproduced your error here using HtmlUnit 2.64, please test with the last version of it! (2.67.0). But unfortunetelly some pages that are builded with javascript comands, some jquery or other complex frameworks doest work well. The javascript engine inside htmlUnit seems not handle some functions. I recomend you trying another headless browser or selenium.(selenium can run headless too).